# Reset AWS Route 53 Name Servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain that I've purchased using AWS. I then hosted my primary site on Bluehost which required me to remove the default name server records generated by AWS and replace them with the BlueHost records.

I'm now moving the site back to AWS but the problem is that I don't have the original AWS NS records handy.

Is there any way to recover the original record values?

Comment: Who do you want to be your authoritative DNS PROVIDER for your domain? AWS or Blue Host?

Comment: I wanted to revert the NS records to the AWS values. I found my answer via a Redit post I found.

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/78b26w/resetting_route53_public_domain_nameserver_records/dosi803